# Imprimir Parámetros en gráfico ggplot como cuadro de texto

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quisiera que alguien pueda ayudarme.
Estoy intentando imprimir un cuadro de texto en un gráfico ggplot, con unas variables calculadas en una función, pero mis limitados conocimientos en el lenguaje me están retrasando. Qué idea me podrían dar para orientarme?.
Gracias por todo. A continuación el código:

```
library(tidyverse)
Proyectil<-function(vi, tetha){
  ymax<- (vi^2*(sin(tetha*pi/180))^2)/(2*9.81)
  xmax<- (vi^2*(sin(2*(tetha*pi/180)))/9.81)
  tiempo_vuelo<- 2*vi*sin(tetha*pi/180)/9.81

  h<- vector()
  d<- seq(0:xmax)

  for(i in 0:length(d)){
    h[i]<- d[i]*tan(tetha*pi/180) - (9.81*d[i]^2)/(2*vi^2*(cos(tetha*pi/180))^2)
  }
  plot(d, h, xlab = "Distancia", ylab = "Altura", col="rosybrown")

  w<-list(d, h)
  datos<-data.frame(w)
  View(datos)
  z<-c("Distancia Máxima", "Altura Máxima", "Tiempo de Vuelo")
  a<-c(xmax, ymax, tiempo_vuelo)
  f<-data.frame(list(z,a))

  ggplot(data=datos, aes(x=d, y=h))+
   geom_point(color="rosybrown")+
   geom_line(color="rosybrown")+
    ggtitle("Trayectoria de un Proyectil")+
    geom_text(x=400, y=50, label=f)


}
Proyectil(100, 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

Los parámetros, entiendo, se encuentran en el `data.frame` cuyo nombre es `f`. El problema es que `geom_text()` no puede "entender" directamente el `data.frame`, sin embargo lo que puedes hacer es generar una cadena a partir de estos datos. Veamos como:

```
parametros <- apply(f, MARGIN=1, function(x) paste0(x[1],": ",x[2]))
label <- paste0(parametros, collapse="\n")

"Distancia Máxima: 882.79858\nAltura Máxima: 127.42100\nTiempo de Vuelo:  10.19368"
```

Con `apply()` hemos aplicado una función por cada fila que lo que hace es pegar del dato de la columna 1 con el de la columna 2 (agregando `:`), a la salida tenemos un vector, y lo que necesitamos es una cadena, lo siguiente es usar `paste0()` para pegar cada elemento del vector en una única cadena separadas por saltos de línea `\n`.

Finalmente podremos usar esta cadena en el `geom_text()`:

```
ggplot(data=datos, aes(x=d, y=h))+
  geom_point(color="rosybrown") +
  geom_line(color="rosybrown") +
  ggtitle("Trayectoria de un Proyectil") +
  geom_text(x=400, y=50, label=paste0(parametros, collapse="\n"))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Una solución alternativa es usar `geom_table()` del paquete '**ggpmisc**' disponible en CRAN. (Por "diversión", ya que no cambia el resultado, eliminé la iteración y llamados a `list()` y `seq()` redundantes.)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpmisc)

Proyectil <- function(vi, tetha){
  ymax <- (vi^2*(sin(tetha*pi/180))^2)/(2*9.81)
  xmax <- (vi^2*(sin(2*(tetha*pi/180)))/9.81)
  tiempo_vuelo <- 2*vi*sin(tetha*pi/180)/9.81

  d <- 0:xmax
  h <- d * tan(tetha*pi/180) - (9.81*d^2)/(2*vi^2*(cos(tetha*pi/180))^2)
  datos <- data.frame(d, h)

  z <- c("Distancia Máxima", "Altura Máxima", "Tiempo de Vuelo")
  a <- c(xmax, ymax, tiempo_vuelo)
  f <- data.frame("Parámetro" = z, "Valor" = round(a, 1))

  ggplot(data=datos, aes(x=d, y=h))+
    geom_point(color="rosybrown")+
    geom_line(color="rosybrown")+
    ggtitle("Trayectoria de un Proyectil")+
    geom_table(aes(x = d, y = h, label=tb),
               data = tibble(d = 400, h = 50, tb = list(f)),
               hjust = 0.5,
               vjust = 1)
}
Proyectil(100, 30)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]